# Entity Framework no reconoce un objeto dentro de otro cuando si existe Entity Framework - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Tags: mysql, c#, .net, entity-framework

se me presento un problema. Tengo una aplicacino desarrollada en .NET 6.0 , en la cual aplique los siguientes conceptos:
•Entity Framework ( Consultas a la base , inserciones y Migraciones).
•Patron repositorio (DDD)
•Inyeccion de dependencias.

Ahora bien, tengo las siguientes tres entidades:
1.

```
public class Reserva
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ReservaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaMovimiento { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaDesde { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaHasta { get; set; }
    public Int32 DiasContratados { get; set; }
    public Int32 Borrado { get; set; }
   
    [ForeignKey("Cliente")]
    public Int32 ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }


    public virtual List<ReservaParticion>? ReservasParticiones { get; set; }
}
```

2. 

```
public class ReservaParticion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ReservaParticionId { get; set; }
    public Int32 OrigenId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaDesde { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaHasta { get; set; }
    public Int32 Borrado { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Reserva")]
    public Int32 ReservaId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ReservasParticiones")]
    public virtual Reserva Reserva { get; set; }
}
```

3. 

```
public class Cliente : Persona
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Int32 Codigo { get; set; }
    public String Usuario { get; set; }
    public String Clave { get;set;}
    public Int32 UsuarioTipoId { get; set; }
    public Int32 Borrado { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ListaPrecio")]
    public Int32 ListaPrecioId { get; set; }
    public virtual ListaPrecio ListaPrecio { get; set; }
}
```

Esto funciona de la siguiente manera: Cuando se crea una Reserva, automaticamente se crea una particion, y esta reserva esta atada a un cliente (que es quien realiza la reserva), pero lo que se visualiza en pantalla son las particiones (que una reserva puede tener una o mas particiones)
Ahora bien, al dar de alta una reserva, automaticamente se crea una unica particion como habia mencionado anteriormente. En el formulario de creacion de reservas, se le pasa por parametro ya las fechas y la carpa seleccionada mediante la pantalla principal, una vez recibido esto buscamos el cliente (mediante un textbox que se ingresa el DNI), y si encuentra el DNI ese en la base, automaticamente llena un objeto de tipo "Cliente" para completar los datos en el formulario automaticamente, una vez configurado todo, se guarda la particion , y estoy seteando de la siguiente manera la estructura de la particion:

```
 private async Task savePartition()
{
    setNewDataReservation(); //SETEAMOS LOS DATOS DE LA RESERVA Y PARTICION
    setNewDataClient(); //SETEAMOS LOS DATOS DEL CLIENTE EN CASO QUE HAYAN SIDO MODIFICADOS
    setNewDataProperty(); // SETEAMOS LOS DATOS DE LA PROPIEDAD EN CASO DE QUE HAYA SIDO MODIFICADA 
    var ParticionDevuelta = (await serviceProvider.GetServicio<ReservaParticionCreador>().Save(this.Particion)); //GUARDAMOS LA PARTICION
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void setNewDataReservation()
{
    Reserva.ReservaEstadoId = Convert.ToInt32(cboEstado.SelectedValue);
    if (Reserva.ReservasParticiones == null || Reserva.ReservasParticiones.Count == 1)
    {
        Reserva.FechaDesde = Particion.FechaDesde;
        Reserva.FechaHasta = Particion.FechaHasta;
    }
    Particion.Reserva = Reserva;
}
private void setNewDataClient()
{
    Cliente.ListaPrecioId = Convert.ToInt32(cboListaPrecio.SelectedValue);
    Cliente.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
    Cliente.Apellido = txtApellido.Text;
    Cliente.Dni = txtDocumento.Text;
    Cliente.Celular = txtCelular.Text; 
    Cliente.Telefono= txtTelefono.Text;

    this.Particion.Reserva.ClienteId = Cliente.ClienteId;
    this.Particion.Reserva.Cliente = Cliente;
    //this.Particion.Reserva.Cliente.ListaPrecioId = Cliente.ListaPrecioId;
}

private void setNewDataProperty()
{
    Particion.PropiedadId = Convert.ToInt32(cboPropiedades.SelectedValue);
}
```

A la hora de guardar la particion en el metodo "savePartition()", en donde el cliente en este caso dado por ejemplo fue encontrado que ya existia en la base, me arroja el siguiente error:`Entity Framework - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"`

Comment: No entiendo el problema

Comment: el problema es que estoy declarando una nueva "ReservaParticion" y una nueva "Reserva" para insertar en la base, y el objeto reserva a su vez tiene un objeto cliente, que este objeto Cliente si existe en la base , y al ya existir yo quiero que lo updatee y no que lo inserte , porque si no me arroja el error mencionado en el problema, el error es el siguiente:
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'" @Yussef, Espero haber sido claro gracias

Comment: Primero haces update al cliente solo y luego insertas reservas sin el objeto cliente, solo con el ClienteId

Comment: Claro , pero estariamos hablando de otro agregado en ese caso, mi idea era hacerlo todo en un mismo agregado, se puede hacer?

Comment: No sé si sería otro agregado.  Perfectamente todo puede ir en la misma operación, desde el punto de vista de la lógica del negocio, tú tienes tu función savePartition y ahí agregas un updateCliente en vez de setNewDataClient. En lo personal, estoy bastante en contra de agregar más capas de abstracción al modelo, y cuando entiendes porque se crearon estos patrones, quienes fueron los creadores y que lenguajes manejan esos creadores (¿Java?) te das cuenta que posiblemente en .net no sean necesarios.